# Second duals of Grothendieck spaces

Tags: banach-spaces, open-problems, operator-ideals

The classical example of a [Grothendieck space](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Grothendieck_space) is $\ell_\infty$. It is also known that its even duals $\ell_\infty^{**}$, $\ell_\infty^{(4)}$, $\dots$ are Grothendieck spaces.

(See, *e.g*., [this note](http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-18-3/18J3Plich.pdf) for the proof of the Grothendieck property of these even duals, which uses the fact that these spaces are $C(K)$ spaces for large Stonian $K$-s.)

> Is it known, in general, whether the second dual of a Grothendieck space is 
>   a Grothendieck space too? Is there a counterexample?

Edit (T. Kania). Let me record here for the future reference that this very question was asked by J. Diestel on p. 105 in

> J. Diestel, "Grothendieck spaces and vector measures", *Vector and Operator Valued Measures and Applications*, Acad. Press (1973) pp. 97–108.

Comment: What is a Grothendieck space??

Comment: I'd just link here http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Grothendieck_space

Grothendieck spaces are also a space ideal in the sense of Pietsch.

Comment: the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572995/second-dual-of-a-grothendieck-space) on MSE

Comment: Moved from edit: As Trond Abrahamsen pointed out, my alternative attempt   
"the claim can also be seen from the fact that they are M-ideals in their second duals, hence have Pełczyński's property (V) and therefore are Grothendieck spaces."
 
 at proving the Grothendieck property of even duals of $\ell_\infty$ fails at the first step, because non-reflexive dual spaces cannot be M-ideals in their second duals.